# Hazelcast unique ScheduledExecutorService on replicated map gets lost on node shutdown

Tags: java, hazelcast, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm trying to run a Hazelcast ReplicatedMap spread over multiple nodes for caching. The map will have about 60.000 entries and the loading/creation of entries is really expensive.

The entries of the map occasionally become invalid, need to be updated or removed or new entries have to be inserted in the map. For this I thought about a scheduled service that updates the map on a regular basis.

To prevent concurrency and costly duplicate creation of new entries there should be only one reload service.

To test this I made a little test case:

```
public class HazelTest {

  private ReplicatedMap<Long, Bean> hzMap;
  private HazelcastInstance instance;

  public HazelTest() {
    instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

    hzMap = instance.getReplicatedMap("UniqueName");
    IScheduledExecutorService scheduler = instance.getScheduledExecutorService("ExecutorService");
    try {
      scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new BeanReloader(), 5, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (DuplicateTaskException ex) {
      System.out.println("reloader already running");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    HazelTest test = new HazelTest();
    System.out.println("Start ...");
    long i = 0;
    try {
      while (true) {
        i++;
        Bean bean = test.hzMap.get((long) random.nextInt(1000));
        if (bean != null) {
          if (i % 100000 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Bean: " + bean.toString());
          }
          bean.setName("NewName");
        }
      }
    } finally {
      test.close();
      System.out.println("End.");
    }
  }

  public void close() {
    instance.getPartitionService().forceLocalMemberToBeSafe(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    if (instance.getPartitionService().isLocalMemberSafe()) {
      instance.shutdown();
    } else {
      System.out.println("Error!!!!!");
    }
  }
}
```

The reloader:

```
public class BeanReloader implements NamedTask, Runnable, HazelcastInstanceAware, Serializable {

  private transient HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Bean Reload ....");
    for (long i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
      Bean bean = new Bean(i, "Bean " + i);
      ReplicatedMap<Object, Object> map = hazelcastInstance.getReplicatedMap("UniqueName");
      map.put(i, bean);
    }
    System.out.println("Reload end.");
  }

  @Override
  public void setHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
    this.hazelcastInstance = hazelcastInstance;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "BeanReloader";
  }

}
```

The bean has only 2 fields for test purpose:

```
public class Bean implements Serializable {

  private long id;
  private String name;
  // getter and setter
}
```

Now when I run this in different terminals on my machine (or over network, does make no difference) the nodes show the desired behaviour: the service is only running on one node at a time - when I start another one I get a DuplicateTaskException.

But when the node currently executing the task goes down the service is not always switched to another node. There is about 2/3 chance that the service is completely lost and not running on any of the remaining nodes.

Now my questions: is this behaviour normal? Do I have to check for running service myself, and if so via what api?

Or am I getting something wrong and there is another way to achieve my goals? Is hazelcast replicated map the right aproach in the first place?

---

Edit: edited the code as the simplifications I made for posting did not show the error any more.

There are no errors in the log when a node leaves and the service is not restored. The only logging is on one node:

```
Mär 06, 2017 9:54:08 AM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection
INFORMATION: [X.X.X.X]:5702 [dev] [3.8] Connection[id=8, /X.X.X.X:5702->/X.X.X.X:54226, endpoint=[X.X.X.X]:5703, alive=false, type=MEMBER] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
Mär 06, 2017 9:54:08 AM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask
INFORMATION: [X.X.X.X]:5702 [dev] [3.8] Connecting to /X.X.X.X:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Mär 06, 2017 9:54:08 AM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask
INFORMATION: [X.X.X.X]:5702 [dev] [3.8] Could not connect to: /X.X.X.X:5703. Reason: SocketException[Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt to address /X.X.X.X:5703]
Mär 06, 2017 9:54:08 AM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask
INFORMATION: [X.X.X.X]:5702 [dev] [3.8] Connecting to /X.X.X.X:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Mär 06, 2017 9:54:08 AM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask
INFORMATION: [X.X.X.X]:5702 [dev] [3.8] Could not connect to: /X.X.X.X:5703. Reason: SocketException[Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt to address /X.X.X.X:5703]
Mär 06, 2017 9:54:08 AM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask
INFORMATION: [X.X.X.X]:5702 [dev] [3.8] Connecting to /X.X.X.X:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Mär 06, 2017 9:54:08 AM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask
INFORMATION: [X.X.X.X]:5702 [dev] [3.8] Could not connect to: /X.X.X.X:5703. Reason: SocketException[Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt to address /X.X.X.X:5703]
Bean: Bean{id=893, name='NewName'}
Mär 06, 2017 9:54:08 AM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask
INFORMATION: [X.X.X.X]:5702 [dev] [3.8] Connecting to /X.X.X.X:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Mär 06, 2017 9:54:08 AM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask
INFORMATION: [X.X.X.X]:5702 [dev] [3.8] Could not connect to: /X.X.X.X:5703. Reason: SocketException[Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt to address /X.X.X.X:5703]
Mär 06, 2017 9:54:08 AM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionMonitor
WARNUNG: [X.X.X.X]:5702 [dev] [3.8] Removing connection to endpoint [X.X.X.X]:5703 Cause => java.net.SocketException {Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt to address /X.X.X.X:5703}, Error-Count: 5
Mär 06, 2017 9:54:08 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFORMATION: [X.X.X.X]:5702 [dev] [3.8] Removing Member [X.X.X.X]:5703 - 875ccc3a-dc10-4c21-815a-4b57ae41a6ff
Mär 06, 2017 9:54:08 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFORMATION: [X.X.X.X]:5702 [dev] [3.8] 

Members [3] {
        Member [X.X.X.X]:5702 - 0ec92bb9-6330-4a3d-90ac-0ed374fd266c this
        Member [X.X.X.X]:5701 - 0d1a832e-e1e8-4cad-8546-5a97c8c052c3
        Member [X.X.X.X]:5704 - bd18c7f9-892e-430a-b1ab-da740cc7a6c5
}

Mär 06, 2017 9:54:08 AM com.hazelcast.transaction.TransactionManagerService
INFORMATION: [X.X.X.X]:5702 [dev] [3.8] Committing/rolling-back alive transactions of Member [X.X.X.X]:5703 - 875ccc3a-dc10-4c21-815a-4b57ae41a6ff, UUID: 875ccc3a-dc10-4c21-815a-4b57ae41a6ff
Mär 06, 2017 9:54:08 AM com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.MigrationManager
INFORMATION: [X.X.X.X]:5702 [dev] [3.8] Re-partitioning cluster data... Migration queue size: 204
```

and on the others basically the same except for the last line:

```
INFORMATION: [X.X.X.X]:5701 [dev] [3.8] Committing/rolling-back alive transactions of Member [X.X.X.X]:5703 - 875ccc3a-dc10-4c21-815a-4b57ae41a6ff, UUID: 875ccc3a-dc10-4c21-815a-4b57ae41a6ff
```

---

Did a testrun with debug logs on 4 nodes (hz1-4.log). Node 4 picked up the schedule. After one run I killed that node (log timestamp 15:28:50,955 in hz4.log). Here are the four logs from that run (note: due to the vast amount of logging I only pasted the logs from timestamp 15:28:50,955 on ...)

[hz3.log](http://pastebin.com/xTWNm5KX)

[hz2.log](http://pastebin.com/EmzWFNVb)

[hz1.log](http://pastebin.com/EW3BA0JU)

[hz4.log](http://pastebin.com/B18B87CG)

With that setup I can reliably reproduce the failure. I just start the 4 nodes with

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="de.tle.products.HazelTest" -Dnumber=X
```

where X is the number of the node (just a variable in the log4j conf file). After all four nodes a running kill the one currently running the schedule and then the schedule is not running on any of the remaining nodes.

Comment: Hi Lasrik, do you see any exceptions in your logs from the members ? I just tried your code above locally, and started/killed members randomly and the task is getting rescheduled as expected. Keep in mind that at most N (where N is backup-count as configured for the ScheduledExecutor) members can go down at the same time. If more, then the task will be lost.

Comment: Ok funny thing .. while revisiting my code I found that the simplifications I made to it (to post it here) make it so that the code works. I will edit my post and modify the code so the problem shows up again.

Comment: how many members do you start and how many do you kill and how fast do you kill them ?

Comment: I'm testing with up to 4 members. After one or two reloader runs I kill the member running the task. If another member catches up I kill that one after another one or two runs. Actually I do no specific timing but try to mimic the scenario in the desired productive system where members will come and go with no guarantees.

Comment: Although I can't reproduce on my environement, would you kindly enable debug traces on your members and share the logs of all members ? For the record, I tried 4-6 members setup, and I killed the member running the task after one or two cycles, and once it got picked by another member i killed that too, until I get down to 1 member. Did this quite a few times, and the task is not lost. I could be doing something different, or it might be something racy. Anyhow the debug logs might give a better insight on the problem

Comment: OK i tried again with 4 nodes (logs hz1.log - hz4.log). Node 4 picked up the schedule. After one run I killed that one (on timestamp 15:28:50,955 as you can see from the log). None of the others was running the updater afterwards. I will post the logs to pastebin and post the links in the question

Comment: Lasrik thank you, can you also share the GIT revision of the code you are using ?

Comment: Hi, sorry I just included hazelcast in my pom.xml, version 3.8 ... don't know how to get the revision of that?

Comment: I posted a bug report on hazelcast about this.